# jgrid validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

i have to put the validation on jgrid cell.

1. Like user cannot be able to enter the any value in calender cell even not the numeric value.

   1. How can i prevent script injection in grid cells.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All form of grid editing inclusive cell editing supports [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) options. With respect of the [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) settings you can implement validation of the data at the end of cell editing. If you don't find the standard validation rule which will implement all your requirements you can use `custom:true` option of the `editrules` and define your own validation function with respect of [custom_func](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example) option.

With respect of [beforeSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) you can make any modification of the cell value **before** it will be validated. So If you know a way how to do script injection, you can prevent this way in your code inside of your custom `beforeSaveCell` event handler.